# Specflow Code behind file is not generated properly

Tags: c#, specflow

I am new to Specflow and C#. Currently, I am facing one issue after updating the .net core as 2 and .net framework version as 4.6.2.

Specflow - Code behind cs file is not getting generated properly. Instead I am getting the below error in the specflow feature-code behind file.

> error Generation error: Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401).

How can I sort out this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FYI: SpecFlow doesn't support .NET Core yet.

To fix your issue, you need the VS Integration in version 2017.1.14 (should be updated automatically - link: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow.VisualStudio/releases/tag/v2017.1.14) and use SpecFlow >= 2.3.0.

Comment: Thank you Andreas!!! I will use the latest specflow version and check...

Comment: problem is solved after using the specflow version as 2.3.2

Comment: There is now a preview of SpecFlow 3 with .Net Core Support. See [here](https://specflow.org/2018/specflow-3-public-preview-now-available/)

Answer (score 4):

The above issue is solved with the specflow older version after doing the below steps.

- Delete the Code Behind file
- Close the Visual Studio
- Open the visual Studio again
- Regenerate the feature file again.

Comment: simply deleting the code behind files works for 2017 v 15.7.5 with specflow 2.3.0; thanks.